# Confusion about subtle difference between discrete-time and continuous-time

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, periodic, complex

In Alan Oppenheim's book Signals and Systems a comparison is made between the properties of discrete-time and continuous-time complex exponential signals in section 1.3 pg. 26.  Specifically it says:

> The continuous-time complex exponential $e^{j\omega_0t}$ has two
>   properties: 
>       1.  the larger the magnitude of $\omega_0$, the higher is the rate of oscillation in the signal
>       2. $e^{j\omega_0t}$ is periodic for any value of $\omega_0$
>
> Consider the discrete-time signal $e^{j(\omega_o+2\pi)n}= e^{j2\pi n}
> e^{j\omega_0 n}=e^{j\omega_0 n}$. From this we see that the
>   exponential at the frequency $\omega_0+2\pi$ is the *same* as that at
>   frequency $\omega_0$.**Thus we have a very different situation from the 
>   continuous-time case, in which signals $e^{j\omega_ot}$ are all distinct for 
>   distinct values of $\omega_0$**

The part I don't understand is the one in **bold** . It seems to me I can do exactly the same thing for continuous-time complex exponential by replacing $n$ with $t$:

$e^{j(\omega_o+2\pi)t}= e^{j2\pi t}e^{j\omega_0 t}=e^{j\omega_0 t}$

So there we have it.  I have produced the *same* signal in the continuous-time complex exponential.  So what are they talking about? I see no difference.

Comment: But $\textrm{exp}(j2\pi t) \neq 1$, except when $t$ is an integer (and then you have the discrete-time formula).

Comment: @MBaz - Thanks. If you answer the question below I can mark it correct.

Comment: Done :)  Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $$e^{j 2 \pi t} \neq 1,$$ except in the case when $t$ is an integer. However, in that case, you have the discrete-time formula: $n$ is assumed to be an integer. In most DSP literature, wherever you see $n$ used as in this case, you can safely assume it's an integer.

Comment: i might add that what is meant by the **bold** statement is to point out the existence of the possibility of *aliasing* in discrete signals.  if one increases the frequency to $\omega_0 + 2\pi$, it **appears** exactly as if the signal was at frequency $\omega_0$.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing you did at first and I could not understand it. But then I realized that the continuous time case was adding $2 \pi$ to $t$, not $w_0$.